# What format does Ansible accept in converting its templated string variables into lists, dicts etc?

Tags: python, json, ansible, jinja2

```
t: ['u']

t_copy_repr: "{{ t }}"

t_copy_yaml: "{{ t | to_yaml() }}"

t_copy_json: "{{ t | to_json() }}"
```

`t_copy_repr` is the idiom in Ansible, right?

But they're Jinja2 templates, and [we're not supposed to rely on repr in Jinja2](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/288)?

`t_copy_yaml` does not behave the same as `t`.  It results in the string value `'[u]'` (i.e. it is missing quotes, it isn't `['u']`).

`t_copy_json` appears to behave the same as `t`.

---

I noticed this while developing the following code in a vars file:

```
test_servers__admins: 
  "{{ 
    users
      | selectattr('admin', 'defined')
      | selectattr('admin', 'equalto', True)
      | map(attribute='name')
      | list()
      | to_json()
  }}"
```

I found `| list()` was necessary to avoid a result like `'<generator object do_map at 0x7ff2ef210320>'`.

Using something like `| to_json()` here matches Jinja2 best practice.  I think it should also help in checking that my list does not contain objects with representations that cannot be round-tripped, such as generators, and copied into another variable.

## Question

Is it *correct* to use `| to_json()` in this scenario?  What set of formats does ansible actually accept in templated variables?  Are there possible outputs of `| to_json()` which ansible would not accept / interpret in the same terms as JSON would?

Are all `repr()` results for Jinja2 string/unicode and int/float types valid JSON?  (And valid for ansible, if ansible is accepting something narrower than JSON?).

Comment: Is it some kind of theoretical question? To use or not to use `to_json` filter is based on task you use this variable in (i.e. when sending POST request, or dumping to .json file, you should use it; otherwise – not).

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Sorry, it may have become less clear once I added the extra tags!  This is an ansible question, affected by the implementation details.  `test_servers__admins` is a list that I want to iterate over in Ansible.  The  Jinja2 project explains why I *must* use `| list()` to get this working, and this is not considered a bug in Jinja2.  In the same thread, they say I shouldn't use `| list()` on its own, I should use `| list() | to_json()`.  I want 1) reassurance as to exactly when `to_json()` is required when I use Ansible, 2) that Ansible actually reads JSON (not e.g. python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are all repr() results for Jinja2 string/unicode and int/float types valid JSON?

No.  repr() as used by Jinja2 will return invalid results like

```
python2> print repr("'")
u'\\\\'
```

neither the `u` nor the `'` are valid JSON.

> (And valid for ansible, if ansible is accepting something narrower than JSON?).

Ansible appears to accept python.

```
# vars file
t: '[__name__]'

# tasks file
- debug:
    var: t

# output from ansible 2.3.0.0 (on python2):
ok: [fedora-25] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "t": [
        "__builtin__"
    ]
}
```

Ansible also appears to use pickle, which has additional limitations.

```
# vars
t: '[__builtins__]'

# debug output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 268, in _feed
    send(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle ellipsis objects
# (and hangs)
```

Google points out that Python is *not* a superset of JSON, because of the different literals for True, False, and None:

```
# vars
t: '{{ True | to_json() }}'

# debug output shows t as a string
ok: [fedora-25] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "t": "true"
}
```

However the ansible implementation does address this for representations of lists and dicts.   I don't imagine it's hard for it to provide bindings for the three identifiers used in JSON (true, false, null).

```
# vars
t: "[True, true, None, null, u'\\', 'True', 'true']"

# debug output
ok: [fedora-25] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "t": [
        true, 
        true, 
        null,
        null,
        "\\", 
        "True", 
        "true"
    ]
}
```

## Answer

For some reason, Ansible makes efforts to parse JSON in string values.  After reviewing the syntax of JSON, I believe Ansible implements this correctly EDIT: except for `"\/"` (which is not generated by `to_json`).

However, it is also guaranteed to parse repr() output as provided by Jinja2.

Therefore it is not necessary to use `| to_json()` for the benefit of Ansible. I don't expect using it would ever cause an error.  However, it is confusing to readers of your code.  They will anticipate your code is talking to some software other than Ansible.  Particularly as Ansible does not actually parse JSON in string variables.

Comment: _For some reason, Ansible makes efforts to parse JSON in string values._ This is made as part of type casting, see [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.2.3.0-1/lib/ansible/template/__init__.py#L389).

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov right, safe_eval() there is adapted to accept a wider subset of JSON, than a python evaluator would by default.  I don't understand why it accepts both syntaxes, particularly when they only interpret a subset of JSON correctly - there's a conflict with python on how to interpret the string `"\/"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `my_list` variable defined as follows:

```
my_list: ['u']
```

then it is a list in Ansible

1. No, you should not use `my_list | list` (btw you can omit empty parentheses when there are no arguments) every time when you want to iterate over my_list elements, like `{{ my_list | join(',') }}`.
   You must use `| list` with projections, that's true (like `with_items "{{ my_list | map('upper') | list }}"`).
   Usually Ansible handle variables internally as Python types.
2. No, there is no need to call `| to_json` every time, Ansible can handle types well enough.

If you want to experiment with types and see when Ansible use what type, you can use this handy custom filter plugin:

```
def get_type(src):
    return type(src)

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'get_type': get_type
        }
```

Place it near you playbook as `./filter_plugins/get_type.py` and  use like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_list | get_type }}"
```

Comment: If this is your answer, how do I know when my expression is a "projection"?  Would you say "whenever you use a filter to generate a list-like object?"

Comment: I know only one way to make projection in Ansible – with `map` filter. Arh.. sorry, yes – select/reject also give projections...